# settings.py file not loaded when using CrawlerRunner in Scrapy in Python

Tags: python, scrapy

I try to debug run on the following code and have a breakpoint in settings.py file, it finished without stepping into that line of code:

```
configure_logging()
runner = CrawlerRunner()

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl():
    # yield runner.crawl(a_spider)
    yield runner.crawl(b_spider)
    reactor.stop()

crawl()
reactor.run() # the script will block here until the last crawl call is finished
```

Whereas if i run with the following code, it will be hit.

```
cmdline.execute(("scrapy crawl a_spider -o %s -t csv -L INFO" % (file_path,)).split())
```

What I'm trying to do is running multiple spiders in one single run, could anyone help me out with the latter solution? Thanks.

Comment: Hi. I wrote a [blogpost](https://kirankoduru.github.io/python/running-scrapy-programmatically.html) about running multiple scrapers programmatically if you are interested in taking a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `scrapy.crawler.CrawlerRunner` doesn't load the settings automatically for you, you'll need to get the setting object yourself and pass it to the runner.

E.g. you may replace this line of your code:

```
runner = CrawlerRunner()
```

with these:

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

runner = CrawlerRunner(get_project_settings())
```

See also: [Run Scrapy from a script (Scrapy doc)](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script)